# Horizontally Center 2 Div Buttons Inside Parent Div

Tags: html, css

Have 2 nav buttons created with DIVs, trying to center both within a parent DIV in a responsive layout. The width of the parent DIV is responsive but the width of the buttons are fixed. Both buttons should be next to each other centered within the parent, with even space on both sides.

Looked at a few other posts about this, tried all the solutions including adding: `margin:0px auto;` - and also tried adding both: `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto` - neither option has worked.

Don't know if it's an issue with some of the button style CSS code that's preventing it from being able to center, or if I'm missing something else.

Here's the code:

```css
#head-map {
  clear: none;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 1%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 0px;
}
#map-button {
  height: 35px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: #12A483;
  border-color: #9dacc8;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px #292929;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px #292929;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px #292929;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
#espanol-button {
  height: 35px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #12A483;
  border-color: #9dacc8;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px #292929;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px #292929;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px #292929;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
a.whitelink {
  color: white;
}
a.whitelink:hover {
  color: #00133e;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="head-map">
  <div id="map-button"><a class="whitelink" href="#" target="new">Map</a>
  </div>
  <div id="espanol-button"><a class="whitelink" href="#" target="self">Español</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why does your #head-map have `width:100%` width and `margin-left: 30%` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're using `float: left;` and causing `text-align: center;` wont work. Remove the float. Example:

```css
#head-map {
    clear: none;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 0px;
}

#map-button {
    height: 35px;
    width: 70px;
    background-color: #12A483;
    border-color: #9dacc8;
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 3px;
     border-radius: 15px;
      -moz-border-radius:15px;
      -webkit-border-radius:15px;
     text-align: center;
    padding-top: 7px;
    box-shadow:0px 2px 7px #292929;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px #292929;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px #292929;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0 10px;
}

#espanol-button {
    height: 35px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #12A483;
    border-color: #9dacc8;
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 3px;
     border-radius: 15px;
      -moz-border-radius:15px;
      -webkit-border-radius:15px;
        text-align: center;
    padding-top: 7px;
    box-shadow:0px 2px 7px #292929;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px #292929;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px #292929;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0 10px;
}

a.whitelink {
    color: white;   
}

a.whitelink:hover {
    color: #00133e;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
  <div id="head-map">
    <div id="map-button"><a class="whitelink" href="#" target="new">Map</a>
    </div>
    <div id="espanol-button"><a class="whitelink" href="#" target="self">Español</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Make the inner divs `display: inline-block` and center them with `text-align: center` on the parent. Remove the floats.

### Simplified example

Note how each inner div has no whitespace between it in the markup. This [prevents extra whitespace being displayed between inline elements.](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
}
div > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  background: #F00;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="head-map">
  <div id="map-button"><a class="whitelink" href="#" target="new">Map</a>
  </div><div id="espanol-button"><a class="whitelink" href="#" target="self">Español</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: keep in mind `inline-block` will added extra `margins`, so make sure to account for those or just know they exist (this is directed to OP, I'm sure you already know this)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add a **wrapper** div around the two buttons as well as a clear div.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJKagE

```
<div id="head-map">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="map-button"><a class="whitelink" href="#" target="new">Map</a>
    </div>
    <div id="espanol-button"><a class="whitelink" href="#" target="self">Español</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Here's the CSS. Note the **.clear** class.

```
#head-map {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 0px;
  background:blue;
}
.wrapper {
  width:182px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
#map-button {
    height: 35px;
    width: 70px;
    background-color: #12A483;
    border-color: #9dacc8;
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 3px;
     border-radius: 15px;
      -moz-border-radius:15px;
      -webkit-border-radius:15px;
     text-align: center;
    padding-top: 7px;
    box-shadow:0px 2px 7px #292929;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px #292929;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px #292929;
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0px auto;
}
.clear{clear:both}
#espanol-button {
    height: 35px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #12A483;
    border-color: #9dacc8;
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 3px;
     border-radius: 15px;
      -moz-border-radius:15px;
      -webkit-border-radius:15px;
        text-align: center;
    padding-top: 7px;
    box-shadow:0px 2px 7px #292929;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px #292929;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px #292929;
    float:left;  
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0px auto;
}

a.whitelink {
    color: white;   
}

a.whitelink:hover {
    color: #00133e;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course, `flex-box` can do this

```css
#head-map {
  padding-top: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
#map-button {
  height: 35px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: #12A483;
  border-color: #9dacc8;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px #292929;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px #292929;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px #292929;
}
#espanol-button {
  height: 35px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #12A483;
  border-color: #9dacc8;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px #292929;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px #292929;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px #292929;
}
a.whitelink {
  color: white;
}
a.whitelink:hover {
  color: #00133e;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="head-map">
  <div id="map-button"><a class="whitelink" href="#" target="new">Map</a>
  </div>
  <div id="espanol-button"><a class="whitelink" href="#" target="self">Español</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above example spaces the buttons out across the page.

This [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/90d8ehbc/) shows them centered with some slight left/right margin added.